# How to inspect variable type in Robot Framework?

Tags: robotframework

I am using Robot Framework to test a system that returns an int which represents the number of errors the system encountered while under test.  However, if the system becomes unresponsive the return will be a NoneType and I receive this error:
`'None' cannot be converted to an integer: TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'`

I'm not able to use the `Should Be True` keyword because a passing response will be 0.

Is there any way to test the variable's type in Robot? My goal is to do something like this:

```
Should Not Be NoneType    ${error_count}    msg=System is not responding after test.
Should Be Equal As Integers    ${error_count}    ${0}    msg=System generated ${error_count} errors during test.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To check that  `${error_count}` is not `None`, you can do the following:

```
Should Be True    ${error_count} is not ${None}    msg=Returned None
```

So long as the previous statement passes, your test can move forward with printing your result like so:

```
Log to Console    System generated ${error_count} errors during test
```

Alternatively, you can merge everything onto one line using the `Run Keyword Unless` keyword:

```
Run Keyword Unless    ${error_count} is ${None}    Log to Console    System generated ${error_count} errors during test
```

Answer (score 1):

The previously provided solutions will work for this original question (where `${error_count}` is an integer or `${None}`), but may not behave as expected for other values of `${error_count}`. A more generic solution to check for None is:

```
Run Keyword If    ${value == None}    Log To Console    value is None
```

With Robot Framework 2.9, the robot variable is available within the Python evaluation space, which allows the following (this is my preferred solution where Robot Framework 2.9 or later is used):

```
Run Keyword If    $value is None    Log To Console    value is None
```

Answer (score 0):

do you need to know when you do get the NoneType's?  You could certainly do what you wish to do, what immediately popped to mind as a simple example which obviously needs expanded upon

```
Run Keyword Unless    '${error_count}' == 'None'
```

More info available here:

http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20If